# Command: git hist ERROR. fatal: option '--graph' must come before non-option arguments

Tags: cmd, gitlab, alias, git-bash, git-config

I am trying to run git hist cmd on GitBash, Windows but I am getting the following error

```
fatal: option '--graph' must come before non-option arguments
```

On window PowerShell, I entered:

```
git config --global alias.hist log --pretty=format: '%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date= short"
```

But still getting the same error.
Please can I know why and how can avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the `--graph` / `--date` options first.

I just tested, from a regular CMD (no PowerShell needed):

```
git config --global alias.hist "log --graph --date=short --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]'"
```

Then git hist works just fine.

Note the lack of space between `format:` and `'%h...'`

Comment: The removal of the space after format was what fixed this error for me. I left the graph and date options at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For me [Mulli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835066/command-git-hist-error-fatal-option-graph-must-come-before-non-option-arg/78220279#comment134763957_70845491) solved the issue as well:

> The removal of the space after format was what fixed this error for me. I left the graph and date options at the end.